# Arrastrar y soltar en Sublime Text

Tags: plugin, sublimetext

¿Existe alguna forma de arrastrar y soltar los archivos de la barra lateral en Sublime Text 3? ¿Conocen algún plugin? Es decir, quisiera tener la posibilidad de tomar un archivo y arrastrarlo hasta un directorio dentro de mi mismo proyecto.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Hasta donde sé, no es posible esto. lo más cerca a esto es [Side​Bar​Enhancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements) que mediante un menú contextual te permite hacer las operaciones `copiar` , `pegar`, `mover` , `abrir` , `editar`  , `duplicar` entre otras

Comment: Pero no permite arrastrar y soltar... sí, también lo instalé y lo uso, pero me gustaría algo que me permita arrastrar y soltar, lo siento más ágil.